# ERROR MicroBatchExecution: pyspark streaming consumer

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, streaming

I'm trying to do some very basic stream processing using PySpark (3.2.4) Structured Streaming, using Kafka as my data source. Just to get up and running, I'm attempting the really basic task of parsing a field changeType from my source messages and appending it out to the console. However, when I run my script I get an

```
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException.
```

See below for script and traceback:

pyspark consumer

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
    subscribeType = "subscribe"
    topics = "test"

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredKafkaWordCount").getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    lines = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers) \
        .option(subscribeType, topics) \
        .load()

    # Define the expected schema
    expected_schema = StructType([
        StructField("timestamp", StringType(), True),
        StructField("message", StringType(), True),
        StructField("iss_position", StructType([
            StructField("longitude", StringType(), True),
            StructField("latitude", StringType(), True)
        ]), True)
    ])
    
    # Use from_json with the expected schema
    value_df = lines.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), expected_schema).alias("data"))

    query = value_df \
        .select("data.*") \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode('append') \
        .format('console') \
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

this the kafka producer

```
import json 
import requests
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from time import sleep

producer=KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                       value_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8')
                       )

for i in range(50):
    res=requests.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json')
    data=json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8'))
    print(data)
    producer.send("test", value=data)
    sleep(5)
    producer.flush()
```

output of kafka producer
{'timestamp': 1703220954, 'message': 'success', 'iss_position': {'longitude': '-30.5346', 'latitude': '19.9839'}}
{'timestamp': 1703220960, 'message': 'success', 'iss_position': {'longitude': '-30.3066', 'latitude': '20.2516'}}
{'timestamp': 1703220965, 'message': 'success', 'iss_position': {'longitude': '-30.0774', 'latitude': '20.5195'}}

error **pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 27d6712d-45fc-4c32-ba01-bda504ea5e46, runId = dbb59a5f-693e-4616-8126-2dc9139ac11e] terminated with exception: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'**

'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'

I've checked all my environment variables and still encountered the error.